Pop!_OS crashes while playing
I'm currently playing Shadow Of The Tomb Raider on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS with my Ryzen 9 5900X, 64GB DDR4-2400 and an AMD RX 7700 XT Nitro+ OC 12GB. After a couple of minutes, my computer would just randomly restart without any information.
I've had a look at the syslog which shows a line full of \00 symbols (3448 characters long) at around crash time. Is it possible to get further information here? /var/log/dmesg wasn't helpful at all (no usable entries).
Thanks in advance.
